# update-alternatives returns error about Java directory not available

Tags: debian, directory, java

I've been trying this tutorial:
[How To Manually Install Oracle Java on a Debian](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps)
to install Java on Debian 8, but I'm getting the following error :
`update-alternatives: error: alternative path /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java doesn't exist`

I checked the directory and observed that the directory actually exists. The output of the `ls` command is as follows: 
`-rwxr-xr-x 1 uucp 143   5730 Apr 10 13:53 java`

I don't know how to solve my problem and fix my Java installation. I've checked about what `uucp` actually means but have no idea why it's there.

I need to get Oracle Java 8 installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be **far** better off using the Debian `java-package` package to install Oracle Java. It allows you to build a Debian package file from the Oracle Java binaries, a package that can be managed using the regular Debian tools (including `update-alternatives`).

For Debian 8.x, the currently supported Java versions are (from [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/java-package)):

> - Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads) :
>
>   - The Java Development Kit (JDK), version 6, 7 and 8
>   - The Java Runtime Environment (JRE), version 6, 7 and 8
>   - The Java API Javadoc, version 6, 7 and 8

Basically:

1. Install `java-package` (`apt-get install java-package`).
2. [Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads) (but don't install) the Oracle Java package from the Oracle site.
3. Use `make-jpkg` to build a package from the Oracle Java installer you've downloaded.
4. Install the Debian package you built as part of step **3**.

For more information, see [here](https://wiki.debian.org/JavaPackage) (currently slightly out of date) and the `make-jpkg` [manual page](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=make-jpkg&apropos=0&manpath=jessie&locale=en).

**Note:** Make sure you remove the Oracle Java binaries you manually installed before installing the package you built with `make-jpkg`, otherwise you are sure to run into problems.

Comment: Awesomely well guided I am. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

`java-package` is of course a better idea.

For now, your problem can be related to permissions.

`chown <current_user>:<whichever_group> /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java` where current_user is the user you want to run java with *(can be root)* and `chmod -R 755 /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05`

And then try.

Comment: I'll surely give this a try too. Thanks for reminding me about the problem I always have with permissions ;)